# Why the linux ps command "sees" the processes ran by K8s pods?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, ps

I have a K8s cluster created in the context of the Linux Foundation's CKAD course ([LFD259](https://training.linuxfoundation.org/training/kubernetes-for-developers/)). So it is a "bare metal" cluster created with kubeadm.

So I have a metrics-server deployment running on the worker node:

```
student@master:~$ k get deployments.apps metrics-server -o yaml | grep -A10 args
      - args:
        - --secure-port=4443
        - --cert-dir=/tmp
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
        - --kubelet-use-node-status-port
        - --metric-resolution=15s
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls
        image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.6.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
student@master:~$ k get pod metrics-server-6894588c69-fpvtt -o wide
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP               NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
metrics-server-6894588c69-fpvtt   1/1     Running   0          4d15h   192.168.171.98   worker   <none>           <none>
student@master:~$
```

It is my understanding that the pod's process runs inside a container running on the worker node. However, I am completely puzzled by the fact that the linux `ps` command "sees" it:

```
student@worker:~$ ps aux | grep kubelet-preferred-address-types
ubuntu   1343092  0.3  0.6 752468 49612 ?        Ssl  Oct28  20:25 /metrics-server --secure-port=4443 --cert-dir=/tmp --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname --kubelet-use-node-status-port --metric-resolution=15s --kubelet-insecure-tls
student  3310743  0.0  0.0   8184  2532 pts/0    S+   17:39   0:00 grep --color=auto kubelet-preferred-address-types
student@worker:~$
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A container is just a process running on your host with some isolation features enabled. The isolation only works in one way: a container can't see resources on your host, but your host has access to all the resources running in a container.

Because a container is just a process, it shows up in `ps` (as do any processes that are spawned inside the container).

See e.g.:

- "[What is a Linux Container?](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/containers/whats-a-linux-container)"

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if a process running in a windows container is also visible to the host.

Comment: If you are running a Linux container on Windows, this is typically running inside a virtual machine so it won't be visible from the host. The answer may be different if you're using Windows containers or if Docker has gained some sort of WSL integration since I last looked.